# Export interactive R graphics to PDF?

Tags: r, data-visualization, interactive-visualization

What R package (*) is able to create interactive graphics like these but allowing to export it to pdf?

http://www.intmath.com/counting-probability/normal-distribution-graph-interactive.php
[image: Plot]
http://www.measuringu.com/normal_curve.php

If yo go to the link you can scroll the green points and see how the graph changes.

The package 'Animation' allow to create animations and export them to pdf but as far as I know it only allow to create a sequential animation, it doesn't allow to select anything inside the graph and the  only scroller it allows is the simple arrow under the graph.
[image]

I know there are other packages that allow some interaction, such as: rgl, ggvis, WebGL, iplots or sendplot,  but I think none of them allow to export to pdf.

Any idea on how to get it?

(*) Combining any package and an external tool would also be useful.

Comment: Two approaches: I already created a movie sequence out of a number of R plots. This can be embedded into pdf. It doesn't support dragging but it worked for a beamer presentation. Another approach I never tried: You can embed even java scripts into a pdf document. Maybe this could do what you want.

Comment: Horts, but how to do it easily from R?

Comment: Then, where else should I move my question?

Comment: I don't need 3D animations, just interaction dragging and selecting inside the graphic. The example I posted about the package 'animation' includes several interactive animations but the buttons are located "outside" the picture, then it should be possible, it's just a question of displacing the buttons inside the image and convert the click behaviour to a drag behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I have in now way tried this, but [it appears](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html) that combing Markdown and Shiny allows for this.

Upon further reading this does not support output as a single pdf, instead it uses html. I suppose this will not solve task, I will leave as a reference for others.